# How to parse only one option of XML in PHP?

Tags: php, xml

Hi I want to parse in php

and read only one option of each line. How can I do this?

I tried:

```
<?php
$xml = file_get_contents("file.xml");
echo $xml;
?>
```

But this read the full xml. I need only one option of the xml

Comment: What does your xml look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

`<? php $xml = simplexml_load_file("path/to/your/file/file.xml"); ?>`

Convert your object into array like this

```
$array= (array) $xml;
```

after that you can do this

```
$option = $array['OptionName'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [simplexml_load_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) and turn your xml into a workable object where you can loop through and find whichever properties you need.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');

foreach($xml->ParkingData as $k => $v)
echo $v->ParkingFacility->ParkingName ." - Vacant Spaces: ". $v->ParkingFacility->VacantSpaces."<br />";
```